# Improve the vertical spacing of "People reached" in Area 51 Discussions profile

Tags: feature-request, design, profile-page, area-51

In my [profile](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/users/210296/ollie) at [Area 51 Discussions](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com), the alignment of the "Estimated number of people reached" label is too close to the "Posts edited" and flagging/voting history labels:

[image]

It looks much better on Meta:

[image]

And on [Chess](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions), where I am also a beginner:

[image]

It might be down to the achievements labeled in my profiles, which helps take up space, but there still needs to be a bit of space there.

Comment: The Bug is *impact related*, if you have a bit of impact [you get normal spacing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkri2.jpg).